# crop a texture in unity

Tags: unity, c#

I am working on cropping a texture in Unity. I have a button, when I click on the button, it takes the photo and the photo gets saved to a folder in the phone. But when taking the picture, I want to provide image cropping functionality for the user.

Here is the sample code to select the particular area for crop.

```
private Vector3 startPoint, endPoint;
private bool isMousePressed;

private LineRenderer leftLine, rightLine, topLine, bottomLine;

void Start () 
{
    isMousePressed = false;

    leftLine = createAndGetLine("LeftLine");
    rightLine = createAndGetLine("RightLine");
    topLine = createAndGetLine("TopLine");
    bottomLine = createAndGetLine("BottomLine");
}

private LineRenderer createAndGetLine (string lineName)
{
    GameObject lineObject = new GameObject(lineName);
    LineRenderer line = lineObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
    line.SetWidth(0.03f,0.03f);
    line.SetVertexCount(2);
    return line;
}
void Update () 
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) || isSpriteTouched(spriteToCrop))
    {
        isMousePressed = true;
        startPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    }
    else if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        if(isMousePressed)
            //cropSprite(); 
        isMousePressed = false;
    }
    if(isMousePressed || isSpriteTouched(spriteToCrop))
    {
        endPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        drawRectangle();
    }
}

private void drawRectangle()
{
    leftLine.SetPosition(0, new Vector3(startPoint.x, endPoint.y, 0));
    leftLine.SetPosition(1, new Vector3(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, 0));

    rightLine.SetPosition(0, new Vector3(endPoint.x, endPoint.y, 0));
    rightLine.SetPosition(1, new Vector3(endPoint.x, startPoint.y, 0));

    topLine.SetPosition(0, new Vector3(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, 0));
    topLine.SetPosition(1, new Vector3(endPoint.x, startPoint.y, 0));

    bottomLine.SetPosition(0, new Vector3(startPoint.x, endPoint.y, 0));
    bottomLine.SetPosition(1, new Vector3(endPoint.x, endPoint.y, 0));
}
```

How can save the particular area of rectangle to gallery?

[image]

Comment: Have you looked into texture blitting operations like [ReadPixels](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.ReadPixels.html)?

Comment: @DMGregory : Yes

Comment: ...yes and...? What aspects are you having trouble implementing?

Comment: @DMGregory : I have tried out a sample for selecting an area with mouse. But I need help to save the selected area to gallery

Comment: Here is a way to save the texture to file. Although it's in Javascript, I'm sure you can convert it to C#. http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/245600/saving-a-png-image-to-hdd-in-standalone-build.html